# How can I make a nginx.conf file to return different web pages for different subdomains?

Tags: nginx, web, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to make my nginx to show a web page for this subdomain: abc.xyz.com and a different web page for this subdomain: abcd.xyz.com. How can I make that?

I tried to change the location block but it didn't work. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should list both domains in server_name directive:

```
server {
    server_name abcd.xyz.com abc.xyz.com;

     location /page {

     }

     location /anothe_page {

     }
}
```

Or create two different servers as follow:

```
server {
    server_name abc.xyz.com;

     location /page {

     }
}
server {
    server_name abcd.xyz.com;
     location /anothe_page {

     }
}
```